# Fixing cases in English text

Tags: nlp, english

I am looking for a program that can fix the cases in a text.

Examples:

- "hello what's up? doing good?" -> "Hello what's up? Doing good?"
- "i called bob Yesterday. he's going to NYC." -> "I called Bob yesterday. He's going to NYC."

Any desktop OS, any license, any price is fine. My preference goes to Windows 7, gratis, open source, Python, if there is the choice, but my main focus is on the quality of the output. I am mostly interested in texts written in English. Since I have a bunch of files to fix, it can be great if it could batch process: CLI or GUI are both ok as long as they can batch process, but I have a preference for CLI.

Comment: Can you explain why you expect a spell-checker to fail? I rarely use them except when proof-reading my books, and there they've worked pretty well so far (LibreOffice with spell checker and [LanguageTool](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/languagetool) – the latter probably filling the gaps you expect, as it also cares for Grammar. Would that combination fit your needs?)

Comment: You can start with capitalizing first letter of sentences. Stackoverflow has answers for [javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441876/javascript-format-lowercased-string-to-capitalize-the-begining-of-each-sentenc) and [Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800401/string-manipulation-capitalize-first-letter-of-every-sentence). Check out [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VAKk8/) from the accepted answer. Common nouns are complicated, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org) with "TextFX Characters" plugin might be your answer.

It has

- batch find and replace (for correcting names)
- Easy to operate user interface
- sentence case (capitalise first letter of sentence)
- cross platform
- GUI
- open source

And a lot more...